# set_error_handler with callback from a custom namespace

Tags: php, error-handling, namespaces

I have an error handling function declared in my namespace

```
namespace Custom\Namespace;
function my_custom_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    die('crash!');
}
```

and I want to assign it to set_error_handler, but if I do

```
set_error_handler("my_custom_handler", E_ALL);
```

obviously I receive this error

> Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument 
>    (my_custom_handle) to be a valid callback

I can't declare the function outside my namespace

How can I do? Is there any way to tell php lo look for that function in the right namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
namespace Custom\Space;

function my_custom_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
    die('crash!');
}

set_error_handler("Custom\Space\my_custom_handler");
```